# Architecture of Java Servlet Browser push notification

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I am implementing sending of browser push notifications via Google Cloud Messaging and Firefox Push Notification System. For this, we have to make HTTP Post requests to GCM and FPNS.

To make HTTP request to GCM/FPNS we should have user registration IDs. Using JavaScript we are collecting registration IDs and storing it in Cassandra. Each record contains user registration information (Registration ID and browser type).

When we make an HTTP request to GCM/FPNS we should send registration IDs along with the request to GCM/FPNS based on browser type (if user registration ID belongs to Chrome we will make GCM request otherwise FPNS request). For example, if we have 10,000 records we should make around 10,000 requests to FPNS/GCM.

Once GCM/FPNS receives the user registration IDs, it will send a push notification to the browser. In browser, we have JavaScript code (Service Worker) to handle the notification event.

For above requirement, synchronous servlet architecture is not good enough. Because to process 10,000 records, it may take assuming 10 to 15 minutes, even if we are using multithreading.  It may cause tomcat memory leakage and an out of memory exception.

When I was searching online, people are suggesting asynchronous servlet architecture. Once we take the request from the client to send the notification we will have respond immediately (something like `200 Ok Added to queue`) and also this request should be added to Message Queue (JMS). From JMS we use multithreading to make asynchronous HTTP requests.

I am not finding the correct way of doing this. Can you suggest a way of implementing this functionality (Architecture Design and control flow)?

Answer (score 0):

Short of changing to something like [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/), I would create a worker queue.  This could be done with JMS or just a shared Queue (search for producer/consumer).  JMS would be, in my opinion, the easiest though it gets harder to distribute in a cluster.

Basically you could continue to have a synchronous servlet - it would take the message, put it on the queue, and return the 200.    Placing a message on the queue would have very minimal blocking - a couple of milliseconds at best.

As you indicated, on the queue consumer side you would then have to handle many requests.  Depending on the latency requirements of your system you may need to thread or off load that.  It really depends on how fast you need to send the messages.

For a totally different architecture, you could consider a "queue in the cloud".  I've used [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) for things like this.  You wouldn't even have a servlet - the message would go straight to SQS and then something else would pull it off and process it.

For reference I don't work for Amazon or PubNub.